# Laravel 8 middleware - Undefined array key 0

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I found no error on my router. but when running an error occurs. what's wrong with my router?

**MY router**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\{HomeController, DashboardController};
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\{Route, Auth};


Auth::routes();

Route::get( uri: '/', action: HomeController::class)->name(name: 'home');

Route::middleware( middleware: 'auth')->group( callback: function () {

    Route::get( uri: 'dashboard', action: DashboardController::class)->name(name: 'dashboard');

});
```

the error message is like this. It's the first time I've come across an error like this, and I looked it up but I couldn't find the same article.

```
   ErrorException 

  Undefined array key 0

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1325
    1321▕             return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
    1322▕         }
    1323▕ 
    1324▕         if ($method === 'middleware') {
  ➜ 1325▕             return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, is_array($parameters[0]) ? $parameters[0] : $parameters);
    1326▕         }
    1327▕ 
    1328▕         return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, $parameters[0]);
    1329▕     }

      +2 vendor frames 
  3   routes/web.php:11
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()

      +4 vendor frames 
  8   app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:48
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar::group()
```

Comment: .i have updated post .why it thrown error.Its just for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `Route::middleware( middleware: 'auth')` it should be like below.

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group( callback: function () {
   Route::get( uri: 'dashboard', action: DashboardController::class)->name(name: 'dashboard');

});
```

**middleware()** not accepting named parameter because its not a real function.it is implemented via magic `__call method` so it does not support named variables.

```
/**
     * Dynamically handle calls into the router instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
            return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
        }

        if ($method === 'middleware') {
            return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, is_array($parameters[0]) ? $parameters[0] : $parameters);
        }

        return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, $parameters[0]);
    } }
```

Ref:https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1318